# How to get user avtar image in xmpp in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i am not able to get user avtar image of say gmail account, using xmpp sdk for iphone.
i am getting only this :

127e080d522c87e162416c78475a7008ebc8935c

but i googled and found that its not an original image(i thought it was base 64 encoded) but its a checksum (SHA1) of user image.

So how can i get all my buddy avtars using xmpp in iphone sdk ?

and also i want to update my gmail avtar image from xppp framework in iphone sdk.

Any help or suggestion will be well appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a new classes available for getting user avtar image in xmpp iphone, its Ext. 0153.